# Interpreting memory usage of game in Go

Tags: go, memory, memory-leaks

I have added memory profiling to my game and when taking a look to the stats I can see something like this :

```
# runtime.MemStats
# Alloc = 1022232
# TotalAlloc = 14369528
# Sys = 72286456
# Lookups = 0
# Mallocs = 192759
# Frees = 184964
# HeapAlloc = 1022232
# HeapSys = 66519040
# HeapIdle = 64667648
# HeapInuse = 1851392
# HeapReleased = 61906944
# HeapObjects = 7795
# Stack = 589824 / 589824
# MSpan = 29920 / 65536
# MCache = 6944 / 16384
# BuckHashSys = 1444778
# GCSys = 2377728
# OtherSys = 1273166
# NextGC = 4194304
# LastGC = 1571576758413809106
# PauseNs = [136190 27071 23449 40823 35342 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# PauseEnd = [1571576480170696886 1571576526952274688 1571576646967831188 1571576688475083354 1571576758413809106 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# NumGC = 5
# NumForcedGC = 0
# GCCPUFraction = 2.6422038270754447e-06
# DebugGC = false
```

I believe I am having memory leaks but I am having a hard time pinpointing the exact code doing it. I believe I have leaks because I can "pause" the game and when I do I basically just continue in the game loop but I dont do anything ( I dont draw on the screen or create new objects ) but I can see the field **TotalAlloc** keeps growing and growing forever, so I assume something definitely must be wrong right?

Here is my code : https://github.com/Matias-Barrios/SDL_Universe/blob/master/main.go

Comment: total allocations are not a memory leaks per se. memory leaks are chunks of memory that are useless to your program but kept in memory by the gc because something is keeping a pointer to it (dangling routine). however, it is a sign of bad memory management and that can degrade your performance. At first you can check https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats to get definitions of the numbers. then you can use this https://github.com/divan/expvarmon to see numbers in real time. finally, run pprof to get a code source listing of your program allocations and identify the faulty statements.

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks for your reply. Ill . give it a shot

Comment: There is nothing in this output that would tell you whether or not you have a memory leak.